# Apache SVR record usage

Tags: apache, proxy, dns, reverse-proxy, service-discovery

I'm looking out a way to use the service discovery SRV record to proxy the request to the behind service, but I cannot resolve that corretly.

```
ProxyPass "/" "http://_service._tcp.privatenamespace"
```

Comment: HTTP URLs use hostnames, not SRV records, so it can't work like this (the name of an SRV record is a domain name in DNS parlance, not an hostname as underscore is invalid character in an hostname, and URLs are based on hostnames). Maybe there is an Apache module that consumes SRV records, but that would be unexpected since browsers ignore SRV records altogether. Besides that your question is offtopic here as not related to programming.

Comment: Also no matter where you ask this question it would help explaining why you are attempting that and what was the original problem because you may have gotten yourself completely in the wrong path. For example if you are attempting some proxy load-balancer and the like, then HAProxy can suit your needs, as it knows how to use `SRV` records. So take a step back and explain really what outcome you want to achieve before detailing any specific implementation (but not here as offtopic, look maybe either at [sf] or [webmasters.se])